# How to search through an arry containing strings, and create a new array with only integers

Tags: python, arrays, string, search, int

If I have an array that contains only strings, but some of them are numbers, how would I search through the array, determine which strings are actually numbers, and add those numbers to a new array? An example of the array is as follows: [ "Chris" , "90" , "Dave" , "76" ]

I have tried using a for loop to consecutively use isdigit() on each index, and if it is true to add that item to the new array.

```
scores = []
    for i in range(len(name_and_score_split)):
        if name_and_score_split[i].isdigit() == True:
            scores.append(name_and_score_split[i])
```

When the above code is ran it tells me list data type does not have the "isdigit" function
edit: iv'e found that my problem is the list is actually a list of lists.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? your code does that currently, are you asking if this is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a list-comprehension and also utilise the for-each property of Python `for` rather than iterating over indices:

```
lst = ["Chris" , "90" , "Dave" , "76"]

scores = [x for x in lst if x.isdigit()]
# ['90', '76']
```

Alternately, `filter` your list:

```
scores = list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you're trying if for integers you can do something like:

// Taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float) and changing `float` by `int`.

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Then you can do

```
[x for x in name_and_score_split if is_number(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want list of int:

```
s = ["Chris", "90", "Dave", "76"]
e = [int(i) for i in s if i.isdigit()]
print(e)
# OUTPUT: [90, 76]
```